# Why Java Stack class (Vector) uses array instead of a reference to the last element?

Tags: java, arrays, vector, stack

If an advantage of a Stack is the fact that its can grow dynamically why java implementation is base on Vector which uses an array to hold the data of the "container" ?

When the capacity of a Vector is reached in Java, all its data are copied in a new array. Why is this considerated more efficient that the implementation below ?

Why not uses this implementation of a Stack ?

```
class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> previous;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    // methods
}

public class Stack<T> {
    Node<T> last;
    int size;

    // methods
}
```

I know that this question is not really specific to Java and may be it's not really smart but i would like to understand. Thanks

Comment: `java.util.Stack` is a legacy; see the API for more recent alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the new alternatives. Even though it is a legacy, early developers could choose another implementation for Stack. But they preferred the vector and array based one. Why was it more efficient ?

Comment: A non-intrusive linked-list stack typically requires an allocation  of a node every time you push something on the stack. That doesn't sound 'efficient'.  And it uses at least twice as much storage per entry as the array solution. The trick with using contiguous storage is to size it initially so that recopying is rare.

Comment: It's more space-efficient than yours, less time-efficient.

Comment: The time-efficiency gets more complicated when you include long lived stacks and GC.

Comment: [*The Collections Framework*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/doc-files/coll-index.html) expands on the rationale.